# What does a consumer of a RESTful events atom feed have to remember?

Tags: rest, caching, atom-feed, etag, atompub

I am researching Atom feeds as a way of distributing event data as part of our organisation's internal REST APIs. I can control the feeds and ensure:

- there is a "head" feed containing time-ordered events with an etag which updates if the feed changes (and short cache headers).
- there are "archive" feeds containing older events with a fixed etag (and long cache headers).
- the events are timestamped and immutable, i.e. they happened and can't change.

The question is, what must the consumer remember to be sure to synchronize itself with the latest data at any time, **without double processing of events?**

1. The last etag it processed?
2. The timestamp of the last event it processed?

I suppose it needs both? The etag to efficiently ask the feed if there's been any changes, (using HTTP If-None-Match) and if so, then use the datestamp to apply only the changes from that updated feed that haven't already been processed...

The question is nothing particularly to do with REST or the technology used to consume the feed. It would apply for anyone writing code to consume an Atom based RSS feed reader, for example.

UPDATE

Thinking about it - some of the events may have the same timestamp, as they get "detected" at the same time in batches. Could be awkward then for the consumer to rely on the timestamp of the last event successfully processed in case its processing dies half way through processing a batch with the same timestamp... This is why I hate timestamps!

In that case does the feed need to send an id with every event that the consumer has to remember instead? Wouldn't that id have to increment to eternity, and never ever be reset? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Looks like I need to order the feeds by an <app:edited> datestamp as mandated by AtomPub. AtomPub doesn't say what to do if these are non-unique though - and nor does Googling! Perhaps I'm forced to process all the entries with the same <app:edited> date as one transaction on the consumer side?

Comment: Answering my own question ... I suppose the <atom:id> could contain a mixture of the datestamp and and incrementing number (say) which was unique for each datestamp. If the atom feed maintained order by <app:edited> and the <atom:id> the consumer need to only remember both of these that was successfully processed last to know where it was in the feed.

Answer (score 1):

Your events should all carry a unique ID. A client is required to track those IDs, and that it is enough to prevent double-processing.

> In that case does the feed need to send an id with every event that the consumer has to remember instead?

Yes. An `atom:entry` is required to have an `atom:id` that is unique. If your events are immutable, uniqueness of the ID is enough. In general, entries aren't required to be immutable. `atom:updated` contains the last significant change:

> the most
>     recent instant in time when an entry or feed was modified in a way
>     the publisher considers significant

So a general client would need to consider the pair of `id` and `updated`.